# Arbitrary separator in pandas csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use an arbitrary separator for reading a very long csv file with six columns. The column separator is '%$%$%', but when I read the dataframe with
`df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='%$%$%', engine='python')` the code gives me a single column
`Out[1]: Index(['Col1%$%$%Col2%$%$%Col3%$%$%Col4%$%$%Col5%$%$%Col6'], dtype='object')`
which is of course not what I am looking for. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the `$` in separator:

```
df = pd.read_csv("your filename", sep=r"%\$%\$%", engine="python")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6]
Index: []
```

---

Why? From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv):

> ... In addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from
> '\s+' will be interpreted as **regular expressions** and will also force
> the use of the Python parsing engine. ...